# Modular property of Weierstrass $\wp$ function

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

For $\tau\in \mathbb H=\{ x+iy\in \mathbb C \lvert x,y\in \mathbb R, \, y>0\}$  and $z\in \mathbb C$, let us define
$$
\wp=\wp(\cdot,\tau): \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb P^1\, , \quad z\mapsto \frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{(m,n)}' \frac{1}{(z+m+n\tau)^2}-\frac{1}{(m+n\tau)^2}
$$
where $\sum_{(m,n)}'$ stands for the summation over the non-zero pairs $(m,n)\in \mathbb Z^2$.

**Question:** for $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ and $z$ arbitrary,  is there a way to express $\wp(z,\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d})$ in terms of $\wp(\tilde z,\tau)$, for a certain explicit $\tilde z$ (depending on $a,b,c,d$ and $z$)?

Thanks!

Comment: You have defined $p$ as a function of a single complex variable, and then you ask about its value at a pair of complex variables.

Comment: @G. Myerson: thanks, question edited.

Comment: Look at $$\tilde{z} = (c\tau + d)\cdot z.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the formula is 
$$\wp(\frac{z}{c\tau+d},\frac{a \tau+b}{c \tau+d})=(c \tau+d)^2 \wp(z,\tau).$$